# Python 3 Limit base 10 input value

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am new to Python so not sure how best to structure this.

I have a user inputing a number stored as B.

The number can only be between 0-7.

If the user enters 8 we print an error message.

Sorry for the simplistic nature of the questio?

Thank you

Comment: _"B can only have an input from 0 -7 the result on b"_. You lost me at "the result on b". Is `b` a different variable from `B`?

Comment: Are you getting these values from the user? Maybe you want [Asking the user for input until they give a valid response](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23294658/953482). You could have `number >=0 and number <= 7` for your validity condition.

Comment: sorry using an iPhone no B and b are the same. I should say the result of b is then added to a so that a starts at 8

Comment: Ok, I think I understand that part, then. But it's hard to answer your question because you didn't actually ask a question :-)

Comment: This question feels unclear. Please edit it appropriately, so that we can answer.

Comment: I want to limit the user input. I.E user can input 0-7 but not 8 +

Comment: Updated answer sorry. I am new and trying to find the best way to explain what I am looking todo. Thank you all for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You can input any base number up to base 36:

```
int(number, base)
```

Example:

```
>>> int("AZ14", 36)
511960
```

If you are talking about limiting the *range* of a *base ten* number, here's an example of that:

```
>>> the_clamps = lambda n, i, j: i if n < i else j if n > j else n
>>> for n in range(0, 10): print((the_clamps(n, 4, 8)))
... 
4
4
4
4
4
5
6
7
8
8
>>>
```

**Amendment:**

To generate and handle errors:

```
>>> def mayhem(n, i, j):
...     if n < i or n > j: raise Exception("Out of bounds: %i." % n)
...     else: return n
... 
>>> for n in range(10):
...     try: print((mayhem(n, 4, 8)))
...     except Exception as e: print((e))
... 
Out of bounds: 0.
Out of bounds: 1.
Out of bounds: 2.
Out of bounds: 3.
4
5
6
7
8
Out of bounds: 9.
```

Answer (score 0):

Constantly asks user for input, until a valid answer is given (`break` exits `while True` loop). `ValueError` is handled by the `try` since it can be raised if user gives something like `1.2` or `hello`. Note that `input()` assigns a string to `user_answer`.

(I am assuming you want an `int` not a `float`.)

```
user_answer = None
while True:    
    user_answer = input('Give a num from 0 to 7')

    try:
        if 0 <= int(user_answer) <=7:
            break
        else:
            print('Out of range.')
            continue

    except ValueError:
        print('Invalid answer, try again.')


print('Given number: {}'.format(user_answer))
```